# How to change source path in executable g++

Tags: c++

I compile my programs in a compiler machine. Later I run and test the programs in a different environment. If I compile with -fprofile-arcs on then the program tries to write a file in a folder which does not exist in the running environment. Is there a work-around for this problem?

Thanks

Comment: It is impossible to have the same folder structure on both machines, and there are no common paths :(. I tried that.

Answer (score 1):

Further to RP's answer, I think [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Cross_002dprofiling.html#Cross_002dprofiling) would be useful.

> if the object file /user/build/foo.o
>   was built with -fprofile-arcs, the
>   final executable will try to create
>   the data file /user/build/foo.gcda
>   when running on the target system.
>   This will fail if the corresponding
>   directory does not exist and it is
>   unable to create it. This can be
>   overcome by, for example, setting the
>   environment as
>   `GCOV_PREFIX=/target/run' and`
>   GCOV_PREFIX_STRIP=1'. Such a setting
>   will name the data file
>   /target/run/build/foo.gcda.

Answer (score 0):

Nakiya, According to [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#Debugging-Options)
"-fprofile-arcs
    Add code so that program flow arcs are instrumented. During execution the program records how many times each branch and call is executed and how many times it is taken or returns. When the compiled program exits it saves this data to a file called auxname.gcda for each source file. The data may be used for profile-directed optimizations (-fbranch-probabilities), or for test coverage analysis (-ftest-coverage). Each object file's auxname is generated from the name of the output file, if explicitly specified and it is not the final executable, otherwise it is the basename of the source file. In both cases any suffix is removed (e.g. foo.gcda for input file dir/foo.c, or dir/foo.gcda for output file specified as -o dir/foo.o)."

Comment: The problem is the .gcda files are trying to write themselves to the folder where object files were kept. This dir does not exist in my running machine. This is the problem.